# How to avoid junk characters in Informatica

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In my customer table, I have one column "Customer_Name" which has Arabic values along with junk characters such as "???" and "^^^". Please let me know how can I filter out those junk values while loading the data from source to staging using Information workflow or plsql procedure.

Comment: Add some of the `plsql` code you tried and got stuck. Your question won't be acceptable without your personal efforts.

Comment: Please review  the [ask] in the help section. Following that as a template greatly increases you chance of getting a satisfactory answer. Keep in mind this is not a "code this for me" function site. It's help, which means showing what you have and what you have tried and a detail description of your issue..

Comment: use a simple regular expression such as ([a-zA-Z]) in SQL Override or inside expression. Depends on where you want to sort the data. I'd recommend doing it in SQL Override.

Comment: And as @AkifHussain mentioned very correctly, you should post your efforts here along with the code or some sample data to make us see the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Java Transformation` with a [Regex Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to extract your substring

```java
String name = "^^^Leroy Jenkins???";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z]+");//this regex only matches alphabetic characters
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
if (matcher.find())//matches the substring and shows any hits
    name = matcher.group(1);
```

Result:

```
name = Leroy Jenkins
```

Comment: Be careful - please check that your code works. The above regex example will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the regex does not define any groups, whereas the matcher assumes one exists. There is also a typo - I think you meant `[a-zA-Z]` not `[a-zA-z]`. Also, the space character (between "Leroy" and "Jenkins") is not included in `[a-zA-Z]`, so you will only get "Leroy" as your match, and not "Leroy Jenkins", if you're not careful.